# 1С: Предприятие 8.2 Документооборот КОРП, Принудительная смена пароля пользователем

Tags: 1с

При входе в систему как реализовать возможность принудительной смены пароля пользователем, если пароль не удовлетворяет нашим критериям (8 символов ...)
Сейчас, если пароль плохой, то выдаётся сообщение "Идентификация пользователя не выполнена" и тогда только Администратор может назначить пользователю новый правильный пароль, а хотелось бы, чтобы пользователь сам (после этого сообщения) ввел новый правильный пароль.

Answer (score 1):

Как установить сложность пароля в "Документооборот КОРП":

- Из режима "Предприятия" сложность пароля устанавливается в настройках программы ("Настройка и администрирование" - "Настройка программы" - "Права доступа" - "Проверять сложность пароля"). При этом, будет установлена минимальная длина пароля 7 символов.
- Из режима "Конфигуратора" сложность пароля устанавливается в параметрах ИБ ("Администрирование" - "Параметры информационной базы" - "Минимальная длина паролей" и "Проверка сложности паролей").

---

При этом, проверка пароля происходит только при его установке. Т.е. если сначала был установлен пароль, а потом включен контроль, то пользователь все-равно получит доступ в систему. Ошибка "Идентификация пользователя не выполнена" выдается если пароль указан неправильно. Тогда ничего не сделать, т.к. платформа просто не пустит пользователя в базу. Если выдается ошибка "Необходимо сменить пароль. Обратитесь к администратору системы", тогда это означает, что в настройках программы была включена настройка "Запрещать вход в программу без пароля". В этом случае могу предложить отключить эту настройку т.к. при создании нового пользователя и так будет контроль качества пароля.